# Issues using useState to show multiple profile pictures of users in chat app React & Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I hope you all are doing well. I have a question regarding this fireship io tutorial in building a chat app in react.

I have multiple users that can send messages the chat app at one time, but it keeps showing the profile picture of only one user for all messages. I have console-logged the photoURL from firestore and it's not null.

Send Message
(This is where I upload the most recent message and copy of the current users photoID as a url)

```js
//Send Messages
  const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { uid, photoURL } = auth.currentUser;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "messages"), {
      text: formValue,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      uid,
      photoURL,
    });
    setFormValue("");
    recentMessage.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
```

UseEffect Method in Chat Message Function
(Update* I've implemented UseEffect to add the photoURL to state, it fixes the late loading of the images, but they're still all the a)

```js
const [photoURL, setPhotoUrl] = useState(
    "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/23/abott@adorable.png"
  );
//Set photoURL
  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.currentUser?.photoURL) {
      //console.log("Photo URL in UseEffect:", auth.currentUser.photoURL);
      setPhotoUrl(auth.currentUser.photoURL);
    }
  }, [auth]);
```

Chat Message Function
(This is where where the message and profile image are displayed)

```js
    console.log("chat message photo: ", props.photoURL);

  const messageClass =
    props.uid === auth.currentUser?.uid ? "sent" : "recieved";
  console.log("useAuthStateHook uid: ", props.uid);
  return (
    <div className={`message ${messageClass}`}>
      <img src={props.photoURL} alt={"profile img broken lol"} />
      <p key={props.uid}>{props.msg}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

Final Product
Tutorial Source Code: https://github.com/fireship-io/react-firebase-chat

I have it set up where I run npm from vs code and I access the app from two of my google accounts. One from firefox, and the other from chrome.

I'm really trying to get a hang of firebase react with hooks, anything helps.

Cheers,

App.js

```js
import "./App.css";

import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

import {
  collection,
  onSnapshot,
  addDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
  query,
  orderBy,
  limit,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = getAuth();

function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>SUp@ Ch@tZ</h1>
        <SignOut />
      </header>
      <section>{user ? <ChatRoom /> : <SignIn />}</section>
    </div>
  );
}

const ChatRoom = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState("");
  const [photoURL, setPhotoUrl] = useState(
    "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/23/abott@adorable.png"
  );

  const messagesRef = collection(db, "messages");
  const recentMessage = useRef();

  const queryAtts = query(messagesRef, orderBy("createdAt"), limit(25));

  //Send Messages
  const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { uid, photoURL } = auth.currentUser;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "messages"), {
      text: formValue,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      uid,
      photoURL,
    });
    setFormValue("");
    recentMessage.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  //Get Messages from Firestore
  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log(messagesRef);
    onSnapshot(queryAtts, (snapshot) => {
      setMessages(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          return { id: doc.id, viewing: false, ...doc.data() };
        })
      );
    });
  }, []);

  //Set photoURL
  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.currentUser?.photoURL) {
      //console.log("Photo URL in UseEffect:", auth.currentUser.photoURL);
      setPhotoUrl(auth.currentUser.photoURL);
    }
  }, [auth]);

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        {messages &&
          messages.map((msg, i) => (
            <>
              {console.log("Pre-Chat Msg uid: ", msg.uid)}
              <ChatMessage msg={msg.text} uid={msg.uid} photoURL={photoURL} />
            </>
          ))}
        <div ref={recentMessage}></div>
      </main>
      <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
        <input
          value={formValue}
          onChange={(e) => setFormValue(e.target.value)}
          placeholder={"Keep it Clean "}
        />
        <button type="submit" disabled={!formValue}>
          ‍️
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

const ChatMessage = (props) => {
  console.log("chat message photo: ", props.photoURL);

  const messageClass =
    props.uid === auth.currentUser?.uid ? "sent" : "recieved";
  console.log("useAuthStateHook uid: ", props.uid);
  return (
    <div className={`message ${messageClass}`}>
      <img src={props.photoURL} alt={"profile img broken lol"} />
      <p key={props.uid}>{props.msg}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const SignIn = () => {
  const useSignInWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={useSignInWithGoogle}>SignIn W/ Google</button>
      <p
        style={{
          paddingLeft: "7.8rem",
        }}
      >
        Do not violate the community guidelines or you will be banned for life!
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

const SignOut = () => {
  return (
    auth.currentUser && (
      <button className="sign-out" onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>
        Sign Out
      </button>
    )
  );
};

export default App;
```

App.css

```
body {
  background-color: #282c34;
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 728px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.App header {
  background-color: #181717;
  height: 10vh;
  min-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 728px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(40, 37, 53);
}

main {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 10vh 0 10vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.25rem;
}

main::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #1e1e24;
}

main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #6649b8;
}

form {
  height: 10vh;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgb(24, 23, 23);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 728px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

form button {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(56, 56, 143);
}


input {
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background: rgb(58, 58, 58);
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

button {
  background-color: #282c34; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}


.sign-in {
  color: #282c34;
  background: white;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


ul, li {
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
}

p {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.message {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sent {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.sent p {
  color: white;
  background: #0b93f6;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.recieved p {
  background: #e5e5ea;
  color: black;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2px 5px;
}
```

I am able to console log the output of the photoURL's and they show their respective links. I've implemented useState to stop the long loading, but it still shows the same image. I'm wondering if I need to create a second piece of state that can hold the second user, or if there's an easier way to set the profile picture.

Comment: Questions must be specific - eg "how do I fix a problem with this exact line of code". Not allowed to ask "there is a problem somewhere in my code, you find it for me"

Comment: Noted, updated the title. Thank you for the note.

Comment: Hey Nyland, it's still really hard to help with this. Instead of telling us everything you tried, I recommend doing some local debugging and then us the result of that. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?